# Jenkins-CI SCP Plugin cannot find files to upload

Tags: android, jenkins

I have Jenkins-CI compiling an Android app I'm working on.  Compiles it great but it will not upload the release apk via SCP.  I have set the source to bin/* and it gives me the following error.  Does anyone have a suggestion on what I have configured wrong?  I've had it working in the past, but I forgot to get the config before I re-installed Fedora on the machine.

```
[SCP] Connecting to smccloud.com
ERROR: Failed to upload files
2: No such file
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2289)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1741)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:1758)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.stat(ChannelSftp.java:1715)
at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPSite.upload(SCPSite.java:188)
at be.certipost.hudson.plugin.SCPRepositoryPublisher.perform(SCPRepositoryPublisher.java:218)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:682)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:657)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:635)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:161)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1400)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)
Build step 'Publish artifacts to SCP Repository' changed build result to UNSTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when I was trying to copy to a directory that didn't exist on the target machine. Create the directory(s) on the target first and this should go away and the copy work.

On the target machine you are seeing something like:

> No such file or directory

when you try to navigate to the non-existent directory.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin isn't working for you can use the shell script with expect, as a post build step, to do it for you.